# UndefinedError: 'current_user' is undefined

Tags: python, jinja2, blueprint, flask

I have a app with flask which works before But Now I use **Blueprint** in it and try to run it but got the error so i wonder that is the problem Blueprint that g.user Not working? and how can I fix it Thnx :)

> app/layout/__ init __.py :

```
from flask import Blueprint
layout = Blueprint('layout', __name__)
from . import view
```

> __ init __ .py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import psycopg2
from config import basedir
from config import config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy()
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    from .layout import layout as appr_blueprint
    # register our blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(appr_blueprint)


return app
```

> view.py:

```
@layout.before_request 
      def before_request():
         g.user = current_user 
    @layout.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST']) 
      def login():
            form = LoginForm()
            #checks if the user is authernticated
            #or not, if yes it skips authentfic.
            if current_user is not None and current_user.is_authenticated():
                   return redirect(url_for('user'))
         #does not allow user to use get method
            if request.method == 'GET':
                  return render_template('login.html',
                            form = form,
                          title = 'Login')
        #taking the user submitted data and checking if it exists in the database
           user_in_db = User.query.filter_by(name=form.name.data.lower()).first()

        #if the username is not wrong
            if user_in_db is not None and user_in_db != False:
                    if form.email.data !=  user_in_db.email:
                           flash('Email is incorrect')
                            return redirect(url_for('login'))
                    login_user(user_in_db)
                    return redirect(url_for('user',page=1,sortby='normal'))
           else:
               flash('Username does not exists')
                 return render_template('login.html',
                        form = form,
                       title = 'Login')
```

> base.html:

```
<div id="bodyAll">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="logo">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('layout.home') }}">
                            <span id="globe"class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="logo">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('layout.new') }}">
                            <span id="globe"class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            Add Monkey
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('layout.user',page = '1', sort = 'normal', monkey = monkey) }}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
                            Jungle
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %} //**Got error here**
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            {{g.user.name.capitalize()}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the point of having `g.user`? You could just use `current_user`.

Comment: to get the id of the user " from flask import g" @BartoszMarcinkowski

Comment: UndefinedError: 'current_user' is undefined @bwbrowning

Comment: Is the error an `UndefinedError` or a `NameError` - e. g. `NameError: name 'current_user' is not defined`?  If the latter, it means that you haven't got a `current_user` anywhere in your current namespace.  Did you import it correctly?

Comment: it's jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'current_user' is undefined @SeanVieira

Comment: @Linda Why don't you just use `current_user.id`?

Comment: well, I didn't know that should I use query.get also? @BartoszMarcinkowski??

Comment: No, just `from flask_login import current_user` and then `current_user.id` in Python or `{{ current_user.id }}` in templates.

Comment: no same error @BartoszMarcinkowski

Comment: Then you probably did not initialize the application (login extension, blueprint) correctly.

Comment: if I delete the {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}  it would work so I think blueprint its okey at this point should I have another blueprint for login ? @BartoszMarcinkowski

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70150/discussion-between-bartosz-marcinkowski-and-linda).

Answer (score 9):

you should register login_manager in **init**.py
try to add this

```
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

Answer (score 3):

The place where you added LoginManager **init**.py or app.py

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
 #Added this line fixed the issue.
login_manager.init_app(app) 
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
```